derived version of Picard functor as a derived stack
The notation originates from the paper virtual Cartier divisor and derived blow up I read recently, in its proof of proposition 3.2.6, there is a derived stack:
$\\$$\underline{Pic}    ^{\simeq}$: $(DSch^{aff})^{op}\rightarrow Spc$, $\ $ $S\rightarrow (\underline{Pic}(S))^{\simeq}$ where $\underline{Pic}(S)$ is the infinite category of locally free sheaf of rank one and $(-)^{\simeq}$ denotes the operation of discarding the non-invertible morphisms. And it claims that this derived stack is $BG_{m}$.
Here are my questions:
About 'the infinite category of locally free sheaf of rank one'
$\textbf{Question 1}$: how do we define the 'sheaf' on the derived schemes (or derived stacks), and how come the collection of sheaves on the derived schemes become an infinite category?
And in such case, how should we define the quasi-coherence of sheaf on derived scheme? Let's start with the affine derived scheme: it's natural to consider the sheaf on an affine derived scheme $Spec(A)$ with $A\in Fun(Poly^{op},Spc)$ as simplicial ring as an $A$ module.
So here is our $\textbf{Question 2}$: how do we define the infinite category of module over a simplicial ring $A$?
For our affine case, the infinite category of locally free sheaf on Spec(A) with A a simplicial ring ($A\in Fun(Poly^{op},Spc)$) is equivalent to the infinite category of locally free module over $A$.
Thus I want to know how we define the 'modules over a simplicial ring' and how they form an infinite category.
$\textbf{Question 3:}$Is the derived stack $BG_{m}$ defined here is the same thing as the underived version stack $BG_{m}$?

You might have more luck with that one at MO.

I don't know any algebraic geometry, which is why I'm just posting comments. The theory of Grothendieck topologies also works higher categorically, so $\infty$-sheaves can be and are defined that way giving rise to an $\infty$-topos [HTT, Chapter 6]. This is perhaps already implicit in the definition of higher stacks. The higher categorical way to define quasicoherent sheaves is to start with a functor $\mathsf{Aff}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathsf{Cat}_{\infty}, R \mapsto \mathsf{Mod}_R$ and right Kan extend this to $\mathsf{Stk}^{\mathrm{op}}$.

Being locally free should then be what you expect it to be. To define simplicial modules, you essentially take a simplicial ring acting on a simplicial monoid on the left. You can endow this with a model structure (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+ring), so this has an underlying $\infty$-category. I'm guessing $B\mathbb{G}_m$ is in the right sense the same as the classical $B\mathbb{G}_m$ but don't quote me on it (or on anything else in these two comments).

@QiZhu Thanks a lot, I recently learn that in derived ag, we usually take the Mod(A) of a simplifiai ring A as the Mod of the underlying $E^{\infty}$ ring and I guess the way you suggest leads to the infinity category of connected modules over A, which stabilization is Mod(A) actually.

As for the locally free sheaf, I guess it should be defined by some Zariski atlas in analogue with the classical case. I was hoping to find a categorical way to define such objects because for the classical case, locally free sheaf on affine schemes corresponds to projective compact object, but I guess this doesn’t work in the derived setting
